# Cannot login after I publish my asp.net web application in IIS7

Tags: asp.net

I published it succesfully in IIS. The problem is that this application run , but when I try to login , it remain in the same page , so I cant log in ,cant go inside my application. It seems like the server redirect the browser in the same content page.

Answer (score 0):

What logic you have implemented in the Login Button.. ?

Are you redirecting the same page after login ?

Ensure you are not redirecting the non authenticated user in the login page PageLoad Method..

```
 protected void LogIn(object o, EventArgs e)
 {
   if(validateCredentials())
   {
        Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx",false);
   }
 }
```